# error /usr/src/app/node_modules/gifsicle: Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: node lib/install.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker-compose, autoreconf, gifsicle

> error /usr/src/app/node_modules/gifsicle: Command failed. Exit code: 1
> Command: node lib/install.js Arguments:  Directory:
> /usr/src/app/node_modules/gifsicle Output: ⚠ connect ETIMEDOUT
> 49.44.79.236:443   ⚠ gifsicle pre-build test failed   ℹ compiling from source   ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -ivf /bin/sh:
> 1: autoreconf: not found
>
> ```
> at Promise.all.then.arr (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> ```

i tried to install packages and all but not working.

Comment: Have you used promise.all in your code where it stops working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I am doing yarn install then I get this error.